# Passing Image and other parameters to controller using ajax post

Tags: jquery, json, ajax

**When i send just the image it works**

```
$.ajax({
       url: '@Url.Action("SaveMeterImageDetails", "saveimage")',
       type: "POST",
       processData: false,
       contentType: false,
       data: data, 
       success: function (response) {
        alert("uploaded");
       }
 });
```

But i need to send an ID as well so i do this and it wont work
please help

```
$.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("SaveMeterImageDetails", "saveimage")',
                type: "POST",
                processData: false,
                contentType: false,
                data: { ProfileID: ProfileID, helpSectionImages: data},
                success: function (response) {
                    alert("uploaded");
                }
             });
```

Comment: And whats your question?

Answer (score 1):

You have to use form data for parsing image and as well as another parameters on the server like given example

```
    var form = $('#fileUploadForm')[0];

    // Create an FormData object 
    var data = new FormData(form);

    // If you want to add an extra field for the FormData
    data.append("ProfileID", ProfileID);


    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
        url: URL,
        data: data,
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        cache: false,

        success: function (data) {


        },
        error: function (e) {

        }
    });
```